# Extrinsic Failed - Contract code rejected while implementing upgradable contract

Tags: smart-contract, upgrade, upgradable-contract

I was following [this example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/upgradeable-contract) of ink! upgradable smart contract. After I uploaded the upgradable_contract.contract (Step 4 in the link), I got the following error:
How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`CodeRejected` means that your contract is using some stuff that is not supported by the `contract-pallet`.

In your case, `seal_delegate_call` is an unstable function at the moment, and it is disabled by default. To enable it you need to build the node with  [`pallet-contracts/unstable-interface`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/blob/main/runtime/Cargo.toml#L62) feature. Or you can use `substrate-contracts-node`, it is enabled there.

Comment: I used the substrate-contracts-node but the same thing happened

Comment: Are you sure that it was the latest `substrate-contracts-node`? Because error means that you are using the functions in the code that is not available